# How to programmatically change "/test/unit/python/tests.py" to "test.unit.python.tests" in Bash?

Tags: string, bash

There are many python files in `test` directory.

```
file="test/unit/python/tests.py"
```

I want to somehow call all of Python scripts for unit testing.

`python -m unittest test.unit.python.tests`

How to programmatically sub-string "/test/unit/python/tests.py" to "test.unit.python.tests" in Bash?

```
$ echo $file    ===> /test/unit/python/tests.py
$ '${file.???}' ===> How can I get test.unit.python.tests 
                =>              or test.unit.python.tests.py
```

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. What you really want is [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery), using `python -m unittest discover`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
>file="test/unit/python/tests.py"
>echo $file | sed 's/\//\./g' | sed 's/\.py//g'
>test.unit.python.tests # output
```

Use with python (removed the `.py` as well):

```
python -m unittest $(echo $file | sed 's/\//\./g' | sed 's/\.py//g')
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome alien code. Uhm How can I use it to call from `python -m unittest test.unit.python.tests

`

Comment: @alfasin: In this particular case, you could argue that it's technically safe to allow `$file` to undergo word splitting and glob expansion, since in theory it should never contain any characters that aren't also valid in a Python identifier, but it would be safer to quote it to avoid possible misinterpretation by the shell.

Comment: @DanielPryden It doesn't matter if they're valid Python identifiers, does it? If they expand, they result in files that don't necessarily exist.

Comment: Notice that this doesn't remove the `.py` (committed this mistake myself), and if all you do is replace a specific character, you can use `y|/|.|` instead of `s///g`.

Comment: @BenjaminW: If glob expansion succeeds then by definition the files *do* exist. Like I said, I don't think this is dangerous *here* but it's not a good or safe practice to recommend in general.

Comment: @DanielPryden Right – but filenames with blanks would break things.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Filenames with blanks break things already (since the resulting dotted path isn't valid Python). But if you let the space characters cause word splitting then you get partial paths passed, and I bet if you had a file named e.g. `--cgi 8000 http.server somethingelse.py` (or similar) you could get it to do something unpleasant.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter expansion:

```
$ file='test/unit/python/tests.py'
$ basename=${file%.py}               # basename is test/unit/python/tests
$ printf '%s\n' "${basename//\//.}"  # replaces all "/" with "."
test.unit.python.tests
```

Comment: That won't work because you need to also remove the `.py` extension. But using a character replacement like that is probably better than my solution using IFS.

Comment: @DanielPryden Oh, right, the extension has to be removed as well, let me update...

Comment: you guys are the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation in pure Bash:

```
python_path_to_dotted() {
  if [[ "$1" == *.py ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
  IFS='/' read -a pypath_parts <<< "$1"
  pypath_dotted="$(printf '%s.' "${pypath_parts[@]}")"
  printf '%s\n' "${pypath_dotted%%.py.}"
}
```

Declare this function, and then you can do something like:

```
file='path/to/module.py'
python -m unittest "$(python_path_to_dotted "$file")"
```